# When should I say "thee"?

Tags: early-modern-english, thou-thee-thy

If I want to be posh, old school, when I'm writing, and decide to use "thee" then what is the correct technical usage for it? Does it simply replace "the" ?

Comment: Good heavens, no! It's a pronoun.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thee

Comment: Generally, only use it when comparing someone to a summer's day.

Comment: Or when you're asking permission to bump the other rappers in the top 10.

Comment: @lonstar +1 I wish I knew how to quit thee! Also, context for those of you who need to get off of our collective lawns: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cj9_yW8tZxs

Answer (score 79, accepted):

To amplify what @Noah said:

**Thee** and **thou** are the second-person singular pronouns in English.  They have fallen into almost complete disuse, as you are aware... but the funny thing is that most native speakers (of American English, anyway; I can't speak for British English speakers) have exactly the wrong impression of what they are for.  The general impression seems to be that English has become less formal over time, and that we all speak familiarly to each other - but exactly the opposite is true!

In languages where the second-person singular is retained, it is only used between people who are extremely familiar with each other; if it's used in any other context, it's essentially an expression of dominance.  (For example: a Spanish-speaking elementary-school teacher, in a *tuteo* country, would call his/her students "*tú"* - but woe betide the student who calls the teacher *tú* instead of *Usted*!)

Most (American) English speakers first meet "thee" and "thou" in the King James Version of the Bible, or in the works of Shakespeare.  In the case of the Bible, we usually first hear the Ten Commandments ("Thou shalt...", "Thou shalt not...", "Thou shalt..."), and it gives us entirely the wrong impression.  A much better starting point is the Lord's Prayer: "Our Father, Which **art** in Heaven, Hallowed be **Thy** name..."  The clue here is that we are supposed to be talking to our actual father, and we call Him "Thee" because He's family.

So if you go to a Renaissance Pleasure Faire, or an event of the Society for Creative Anachronism, and you hear people "speaking forsoothly" (yes, that's actually what they call it!), prepare to be amused.  In the actual Middle Ages, a commoner who addressed the Queen as "thee" would have been taught a rough lesson in short order.

In modern English usage, we don't use the second-person singular; what we use in its place is essentially the second-person plural - so it's not just Southerners who call each other "you-all"; we all do it!  To see what I mean by this, consider the standard conjugation diagram, as seen in countless "501 xxxxish Verbs" books:

Modern English usage:

```
I    am   we   are   I    have  we   have    I    will  we   will   I   do    we   do
you  are  you  are   you  have  you  have    you  will  you  will   you do    you  do
he   is   they are   he   has   they have    he   will  they will   he  does  they do
```

Old usage:

```
I    am   we   are   I    have  we   have    I    will  we   will   I    do    we   do
thou art  you  are   thou hast  you  have    thou wilt  you  will   thou dost  you  do
he   is   they are   he   has   they have    he   will  they will   he   does  they do
```

In modern usage, we also use "you" as both the subject pronoun (who's doing it?) and the object pronoun (to whom is it being done?)  Formerly, in the second-person singular, "thou" would be the subject pronoun, and "thee" would be the object pronoun:

> Modern:  I love **you**.   Do **you** love me?
> Old:     I love **thee**.  Dost **thou** love me?

Finally, **thy** and **thine** are the second-person singular equivalents of **your** and **yours**.  To help you remember when to use which, try substituting "my" and "mine" instead.

> **Thy** chair is on the right.
> The chair on the right is **thine**.

**Thine** and **mine** are used in place of **thy** or **my** before a vowel sound, just like **a** and **an**.

> This is **a** cap.
> This is **an** apple.
>
> This is **my** cap.
> This is **mine** apple.
>
> This is **thy** cap.
> This is **thine** apple.

Comment: I've been fascinated for a long time by the fact that in some languages (English "you", French "vous", Russian "вы") the "polite" mode is formed by using the second-person plural - essentially, in order to be polite, we speak to the other person as if s/he were a group - while in other languages (Spanish "Usted", short for "vuestra merced": "your mercy"; German "Sie", meaning "they") we essentially speak to an imaginary third person (or persons, in the case of German!)  It truly is a funny old world.

Comment: English once did the same (see my answer). I suspect we have to look for the reason we no longer do so in social rather than linguistic developments.

Comment: English once used 2nd person plural pronouns as polite singular forms.

Comment: @BarrieEngland - We still do; we just lost the habit of distinguishing between formal and informal.

Comment: That's what I meant. Posted in haste. We once distinguished, but no longer do so.

Comment: Italian language shows different usages of other person modes when switching to the polite registry. I don't know the historical context of these forms, but currently (in order of likeliness to be used) you can adopt the 3rd singular female person ("Lei"), the 2nd plural ("Voi") or event the archaic 3rd plural ("Loro").

Comment: @ErikBurigo - Thanks!  I just _knew_ there had to be a language that made things even weirder than they already were, and I'm relieved to know that it's Italian.  <g>

Comment: It's not just old usage, you should also check out the [Yorkshire dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yorkshire_dialect#Vocabulary_and_grammar).

Comment: In Brazilian portuguese, the 2nd-person plural "tu" (thou) or 2nd-person plural "vós" (thy) should be used with who you are familiar, but aren't used anymore, even in polited situations, and just remain in use in the south of the country (near spanish-speaking countries Uruguay and Argentina). The modern way is "você" and "vocês", but with verb in the 3rd-person... The polited forms are indirect: "o senhor" (Mister)...

Comment: Thanks to @tcovo for catching my subject/object reversal!

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a mention of the prevocalic *thine*.

Comment: @JonPurdy - Thanks!  I suspect I could have written a much longer screed, but I'm frankly amazed that people appear to be reading the whole thing as it stands...

Comment: @MT_Head, what exactly is 'British English'? Is it a funny amalgamation of Welsh English, Irish English, Scottish English and English English?

Comment: @TheQueenofEngland - Of course there are major differences between Welsh, Irish, Scottish and English varieties of English... just as there are major differences between Southern, Mid-Atlantic, New England, Midwest, Southwest, and Pacific Northwest American English.  However, we tend to find that (apart from the odd regional colloquialism) the intra-national differences are smaller than the international ones - and so, on this site, we tend to distinguish between "British" and "American" English.  If this was not a serious question, of course - nice troll, Your Majesty.

Comment: Hindi uses the second pers. pl. (aap) in most cases for the singular, just as we do. To make it clear that one is addressing more than one person, 'aap lohg' (you people) may be used - you sometimes hear Indians say 'you people' in English for this reason; unfortunately, it sounds a bit deprecating in English. The second pers. sing. (tu) is current but is used for very close relationships, talking to small children (or animals), addressing God (who is in one's heart), or for deliberately talking down to someone.

Answer (score 11):

Here’s a brief history adapted from [‘The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language’](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521736501) by David Crystal:

> **Old English**: *thou* singular, *ye* plural as subject. *Thee* and *you*
>   as object. 
>   **Middle English**: *ye* and *you* used alongside *thou* and
>   *thee* as polite singular forms. **Early Modern English**: Distinction between *ye* as subject and *you* as object disappeared, *you* being
>   used almost universally. *Ye* restricted to archaic, religious or
>   literary contexts by the end of the 16th century. *Thou* similarly
>   restricted by 1700.

*Ye* is sometimes misunderstood as an archaic form of *the*, because of the resemblance of *y* to the Old English letter thorn, used to represent both the voiced and unvoiced 'th' sound.

Comment: It's not a misunderstanding of *ye*. The thorn really was often printed as *y*, so in phrases like "Ye Olde Shoppe", the *Ye* really does mean *The* (and is pronounced as *the*, because that's what it is). In phrases like "hear ye, hear ye", the *y* really is a *y*, and *ye* means *you* (plural).

Comment: @JohnY: Not where I live.

Comment: Do you have any reliable sources stating that y and þ resembled each other as opposed to printers using y because they didn't have a thorn available?

Comment: @Samuel Edwin Ward: Nope.

Comment: Why can't it be both? After all that is how languages slowly evolve over time.

Answer (score 8):

**Thee** is a pronoun and is the archaic or dialect form of **you** not **the**. It's only used as second person singular compared to *you* which is used for both singular and plural.

> We beseech **thee** O lord. We beseech **you** O lord.

Ref. Oxford dictionary.

Comment: And it's used when you need a direct object. "*Thou*" is used when used as the subject.